# PHP Extension bcmath is missing in PHP Extensions Check

Tags: magento2, centos, ubuntu, php-extension

I found a lot of questions on this topic. but sorry, nothing can resolve my issue.

I am using virtual box to run centos 7. 
I have downloaded Magento 2.3.
I tried `composer install` on my Magento folder and it returns the error,

```
moontoast/math 1.1.2 requires ext-bcmath * -> the requested PHP extension bcmath is missing from your system
```

so I searched for this error, and I got an answer to install `bcmath` with the command

```
sudo yum install php7.2-bcmath
```

at this time, I faced another issue, like 
[image: error]

and again searched for this and got another answer to try out with

```
sudo yum install php7.2-bcmath --disablerepo=epel\*
```

I ran this command, and the result shows like below,

[image]

and the thing is that I am just trying to configure Magento. I spent 3 days on it. really fed up. I got stuck.

Please help me to go forward. 
still, I am facing the issue with

```
moontoast/math 1.1.2 requires ext-bcmath * -> the requested PHP extension bcmath is missing from your system
```

my `php -v` is

```
PHP 7.2.9 (cli) (built: Aug 25 2018 14:12:18) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.2.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
with Xdebug v2.6.1, Copyright (c) 2002-2018, by Derick Rethans
with Zend OPcache v7.2.9, Copyright (c) 1999-2018, by Zend Technologies
```

Comment: what is the php version ? if it is 7.1 then use this command
"sudo yum install php7.1-bcmath"

Comment: PHP 7.2.9 (cli) (built: Aug 25 2018 14:12:18) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.2.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v2.6.1, Copyright (c) 2002-2018, by Derick Rethans
    with Zend OPcache v7.2.9, Copyright (c) 1999-2018, by Zend Technologies

Comment: Try using "sudo yum install php-bcmath"

Comment: Throwing new issue
`Packages skipped because of dependency problems:
    php-bcmath-5.4.16-46.el7.x86_64 from base
`

Comment: sudo yum install php72w-bcmath  try this

Comment: @surbhiagr . I dont know, How to thank you. it worked. I just added `--disablerepo=epel\*` with the command you gave.

Really thanks a lot. :-) 
you saved my life toooooo

Comment: No problem! Glad i could help :)

Comment: I have posted it as answer so that others may also benefit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve it with the help of following command

```
sudo yum install php72w-bcmath --disablerepo=epel\*
```